# C++ index-to-index map

Tags: c++, vector

I have a list of IDs (integers).
They are sorted in a really efficient way so that my application can easily handle them, for example

```
9382
297832
92
83723
173934
```

(this sort is really important in my application).

Now I am facing the problem of having to access certain values of an ID in another vector.

For example certain values for ID 9382 are located on someVectorB[30].

I have been using

```
const int UNITS_MAX_SIZE = 400000;

class clsUnitsUnitIDToArrayIndex : public CBaseStructure
{
private:
    int m_content[UNITS_MAX_SIZE];
    long m_size;
protected:
    void ProcessTxtLine(string line);
public:
    clsUnitsUnitIDToArrayIndex();
    int *Content();
    long Size();
};
```

But now that I raised UNITS_MAX_SIZE to 400.000, I get page stack errors, and that tells me that I am doing something wrong. I think the entire approach is not really good.

What should I use if I want to locate an ID in a different vector if the "position" is different?

ps: I am looking for something simple that can be easily read-in from a file and that can also easily be serialized to a file. That is why I have been using this brute-force approach before.

Comment: Did you consider using `std::map` ?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if your current m_content array exceeded the size of the stack which would be causing your immediate error. Regardless this approach seems off. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to keep a list that tells me on which position on a vector a certain ID is located.

Comment: Yes, I considered std::map, but I was concerned about the speed. My old approach is ultimately fast, I think.

Comment: Is the issue the stack overflow or that you want a new design? 1.6M or so (assuming 32 bit int) is not a lot - just allocate the array on the heap.

Comment: This really feels like there is a major design issue. What are you using this code to do? The snippet suggests you're trying to do some text manipulation or parsing but the design doesn't make sense in that context. The question is hard to answer in a useful manner in it's current form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a mapping from int's to int's and your index numbers non-consecutive you should consider a `std::map`. In this case you would define it as such:

```
std::map<int, int> m_idLocations;
```

A map represents a mapping between two types. The first type is the "key" and is used for lookup up the second type known as the "value". For each id lookup you can insert it with:

```
m_idLocations[id] = position;
// or
m_idLocations.insert(std::pair<int,int>(id, position));
```

And you can look them up using the following syntax:

```
m_idLocations[id];
```

Typically a `std::map` in the stl is implemented using [red-black trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) which have a worse-cast lookup speed of O(log n). This is slightly slower then O(1) that you'll be getting from the huge array however it's a substantially better use of a space and you're unlikely to notice the difference in practise unless you're storing truly gigantic amounts of numbers or doing an enourmous amount of lookups.

**Edit:**

In response to some of the comments I think it's important to point out that moving from O(1) to O(log n) can make a significant difference in the speed of your application not to mention practical speed concerns from moving to fixed blocks of memory to tree based structure. However I think that it's important to initially represent what you're trying to say (an int-to-int) mapping and avoid the pitfall of premature optimization.

After you've represented the concept you should then **use a profiler** to determine if and where the speed issues are. If you find that the map is causing issues then you should look at replacing your mapping with something that you think will be quicker. **Make sure to test that the optimization helped** and don't forget to include a big comment about what you are representing and why it needed to be changed.

Comment: The values in the 2 vectors are the same, but they are mixed, for example vector1: 43, 98, 11 and vector2: 98, 11, 43

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But since I have so much data (400.000*2 IDs perhaps really too much for the RAM), should I perhaps get it from the file using file mapping and then simply use memcopy to retrieve the values? My code is huge, and for simply trying it out, I need several hours, that is why I would like to ask in advance if my approach seems logical.

Comment: 800,000 id's is relatively tiny for a logarithmic operation. To put it into perspective log(800000) ~= 5.903 which is tiny on the scale of large computations. Copying that much data would be much slower then performing some map lookups. Though all of this depends on how your application is put together.

Comment: My application is a computer voice that needs to combine small pieces of audio to new words. It looks up thousands of possible units, so it is rather processing intensive and still something that needs to run on a simple customer computer, not some university project or so. Is keeping such a (for my ideas big) map in RAM a valid approach on a normal customer computer?

Comment: I would estimate that it would be fine. However programmers are notoriously bad at estimates like that so what I would suggest is that you implement this in a class and then profile the entire program. Profiling will identify bottlenecks in the system and if it turns out the std::map is too slow you can look at other options such as a large vector, unordered_map or other optimizations. When in doubt: profile.

Comment: @JakeWoods: I completely disagree with your statements about performance. Despite the larger overhead of std::map with respect to a - in principal - linear array like std::vector, going from a O(1) to O(log(N)) complexity is a big change from design point of view. What you are telling is, that a factor 6 (log(800000)) does not matter. I say: it does. Of course it depends on the particular application, but as the OP stressed in his initial question, the performance of his lists matters a lot. However, I completely agree with your profiling statement. "Early optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: @JakobS. You're right. I have understated the impact of performance as in some situations it will make a significant difference. My feeling is that the OP is prematurely optimizing and should be considering what he is trying to represent (an int-to-int mapping) rather then worying about to-the-metal speed but as you said it's hard to tell without more information.

Comment: @Jakob S Should I explain my application more in detail? I guess that would be helpful, but it would turn into a discussion...

Comment: @Jake Woods In my original code, I had "int *Content();". That would no longer be needed right? "m_idLocations" can be public and does not need a private declaration, right?

Comment: @tmighty It's hard to tell what you used Content() for without more information. It might be worthwhile editing the question with more information about the context in which your int-to-int mapping is going to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are getting stackoverflow error due to int m_content[UNITS_MAX_SIZE]. The array is allocated on the stack and 400000 is a pretty big number for the stack. You can use std::vector instead, it is dynamically allocated and you can return a reference of vector member to avoid copy operation:

```
std::vector<int> m_content(UNITS_MAX_SIZE);

const std::vector<int> &clsUnitsUnitIDToArrayIndex::Content() const
{
   return m_content;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between dynamic allocation and fixed allocation when in the end, both become the same size? For example, if I really have 400.000 ids in the vector, it doesn't matter if allocated dynamically or right-away, does it?

Comment: @tmighty, fixed allocation is allocated on the stack and stack has some limited size but limits of dynamic allocation is limited to your available RAM. If you want o use huge arrays like that, you may avoid stackoverflow problem by using standard containers like std::vector or you can define you array on the heap wtih keyword new

Comment: Could you please tell me how I could then access the vector from outside? My "int *Content();" is obsolete. And I think you mistyped. Shouldn't it be "std::vector<int> m_content();" ?

Answer (score 1):

if nothing else works you can just allocate the array dynamically in the constructor. this will move the large array on the heap and avoid your page stack error. you should also remember to release the resource while destroying your `clsUnitsUnitIDToArrayIndex`

But the recommended usage is as suggested by other members, use a std::vector or std::map